# Paste password into composer

Tags: php, git, ssh, composer-php

It may be a trivial question, but not knowing the answer make things harder. So I'm using composer through Windows CMD. I've got a private GIT repository that composer access through SSH username/password. Problem is Ctrl+V and PPM not working when composer is asking for password. Is there any way to paste the password?

Comment: Right click on the top bar which says C:\ something something then go to edit and paste. You are sorted.

Comment: sounds silly but you might also be able to copy the text and drop it into CMD

Comment: drag&drop isn't working with CMD (on my comp at least) and while composer is asking for password - PPM prompt cannot be showed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ssh key authentication provider like Pageant (included with Putty) and use SSH keys to authenticate. It will make your life way easier. No need to ever paste passwords into shells.